# Pandas .apply() function with multiple args

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

df = rocksfile [snapshot of my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqZAo.png)

Question: Write a function that will take a row of a DataFrame and print out the song, artist, and whether or not the release date is < 1970.

Defining my function:

```
def release_info(row):
    """Checks if song is released before or after 1970."""
    if rocksfile.loc[row, 'Release_Year'] < 1970:
        print str(rocksfile.loc[row,'Song_Clean']) + " by " + 
str(rocksfile.loc[row,'Artist_Clean']) \
            + " was released before 1970."
    else:
        print str(rocksfile.loc[row,'Song_Clean']) + " by " + str(rocksfile.loc[row,'Artist_Clean']) \
            + " was released after 1970."
```

Using the .apply() function, apply the function you wrote to the first four rows of the DataFrame.
You will need to tell the apply function to operate row by row. Setting the keyword argument as axis=1 indicates that the function should be applied to each row individually.

Using .apply:

```
rocksfile.apply(release_info, axis = 1, row=1)
```

Error Message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-fe0405b4d1e8> in <module>()
  1 #a = [1]
  2 
----> 3 rocksfile.apply(release_info, axis = 1, row=1)


TypeError: ("release_info() got multiple values for keyword argument 'row'", u'occurred at index 0')
```

release_info(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.where` and reduce this to 1 line.

```
s = rocksfile['Song_Clean'] 
    + ' was released by ' 
    + rocksfile['Artist_Clean'] 
    + pd.Series(np.where(rocksfile['Release_Year'] < 1970, 'before', 'after'))
    + ' 1970'

rocksfile['new'] = s
```

Answer (score 2):

In pandas working with `array`s (`Series`, `DataFrames`) so better is used vectorized `pandas` or `numpy` function, here the best is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
#condition
m = rocksfile['Release_Year'] < 1970
#concatenate columns together
a = rocksfile['Song_Clean'] + " by " + rocksfile['Artist_Clean']
#add different string to end
b =  a + " was released before 1970."
c =  a + " was released after 1970."

rocksfile['new'] = np.where(m, a, b)
print (rocksfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
rocksfile.apply(release_info, axis = 1, row=1)
```

`row` is not part of `DataFrame.apply()` expected arguments, so [it get passed as a keyword arg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to `release_info()`, **in addition of the first positional argument**, so `release_info()` ends up being called like this:

```
release_info(row_index, row=1)
```